# Excel Plugin for ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, web-applications, openoffice.org

I am working on an ASP.NET application. I want to embed/display (if possible) an Excel file into the application (in my browser), such that all of its functionality, like adding expressions and filters, is present. It's a cloud-based application and I would prefer an open source (OpenOffice?) solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really embed an excel file and have it displayed on your site. The best you can do is try to use your excel file as a data source for something like the [grid control](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx) from Telerik. It has pretty advanced functionality, but still doesn't approach Excel itself, so you'd have to test to see if it does what you need.

As for open source options, there are definitely solutions for displaying grids of data, but none of them have really advanced functionality unless you program it yourself.

Comment: Thanks charles! Gird control seems the way out for now. I need an interface where user could specify formulae on cells of grid. I checked out obout grid package, but didnt found any solution which fits my need. Telerik is way too expensive..

Comment: if Tlelerik is too expensive, McDonalds allows you to earn money (they are actually quite cheap). That said, I know of no  solution with fomulas that applies to websites. Sorry, no easy drop here. Start programming.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Office Web Component can do this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure licensing for those require the users of the web app to have Office running on the computer accessing the site, so that wouldn't really work for a public application very well. Also, OWC has been discontinued and some aspects of it don't work in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can host an Excel file via Sharepoint + Office Web Apps and then embed your file (hosted by Office Web Apps) via an iFrame on your page. Running your own Windows Server 2008 R2 + Sharepoint + Office Web Apps is pretty expensive in licensing terms, but there are many "hosted sharepoint" providers now-a-days.

You can also put in SkyDrive (Public folder) : [Example](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=a4185e96243b90af&resid=A4185E96243B90AF!423&parid=A4185E96243B90AF!101&authkey=!ADv45tqo5dFqirM)

Excel files on SkyDrive can be embedded on other web page (via iFrames) just like an eqivalent Google Docs document. Detailed instructions from Microsoft [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps-help/embed-an-excel-workbook-on-a-web-page-HA102029502.aspx)